# R: replace values between two data.frames given two conditions, without altering non-matches

Tags: r, replace

I'm aware there are more questions on this topic, so far I got no solution working for my case. 
I have two datasets :

- `movers` contains data about relocations. There is some missing data in there in the 'old' postal codes.
- `inhabitants` contains data about all the inhabitants

I would like to replace the empty postal codes in `movers`, with the postal codes in `inhabitants`, but without altering the postal codes that are known.

The key column would be their personal number.

Closest I came to something that worked was: having two subsets, `movers` with empty postal codes, and `inhabitants` matched on the same personal number:

```
moversEmpty$postalcodeold <-
  inhabEmpty$postalcode[match(moversEmpty$personalnumber, inhabEmpty$a_number)]
```

This works. However: If I do this over the complete dataset, it replaces all the 'known' postal codes with `NULL` since there is no match.

Note: I don't want to use the complete `inhabitants` dataset to replace all the values since that would 'pollute' so to say the dataset as it is delivered to us.

Example data:

*Note this is very much simplified for this question. The complete `inhabitants` dataset contains around 10.800 rows. The real `movers` dataset around 6500 and both have around 40 columns.*

```
moversEmpty <- data.frame(list(personalnumber = c(12345, 23456, 35678), postalcodeold = c("      ", "      ","      ")))
inhabEmpty <- data.frame(list(a_number = c(12345, 23456, 35678), postalcode = c("1811BH", "1811LH", "1814XS")))
moversExample <- data.frame(list(personalnumber = c(12345, 23456, 35678, 45698, 23651), postalcodeold = c("      ", "      ","      ", "1911HK", "1715PH")))
```

So the code works for `moversEmpty` and `inhabEmpty`, but say I want to use it on `moversExample`, the 'known' postal codes end up with the `NULL` value.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a `join` or `merge` like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

moversExample %>%
  left_join(inhabEmpty, by = c("personalnumber" = "a_number")) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
  mutate(postalcode_final = if_else(is.na(postalcode), postalcodeold, postalcode))

#   personalnumber postalcodeold postalcode postalcode_final
# 1          12345                   1811BH           1811BH
# 2          23456                   1811LH           1811LH
# 3          35678                   1814XS           1814XS
# 4          45698        1911HK       <NA>           1911HK
# 5          23651        1715PH       <NA>           1715PH
```

Comment: I'm not convinced that this would be a 'pre-requisite', but we could always throw a `mutate(postalcodeold = str_replace(postalcodeold, "\\s+", "")) %>%` before the `left_join` for good measure...even more simply, a `str_squish`: `mutate(postalcodeold = str_squish(postalcodeold))`

Comment: `coalesce` might be more succinct here than an `if_else`

Answer (score 1):

First, let's make everything relevant `character` instead of `factor`:

```
inhabEmpty$postalcode = as.character(inhabEmpty$postalcode)
moversExample$postalcodeold = as.character(moversExample$postalcodeold)
```

Then, let's use R's built-in missing value character, `NA`, for missing values instead of a few spaces:

```
# this well replace any strings that are just spaces with NA
moversExample$postalcodeold[grepl("^ +$", moversExample$postalcodeold)] = NA
```

And now we can use match, only replacing the `NA` rows:

```
moversExample$postalcodeold[is.na(moversExample$postalcodeold)] = 
  inhabEmpty$postalcode[match(inhabEmpty$a_number, moversExample$personalnumber[is.na(moversExample$postalcodeold)])]

moversExample
#   personalnumber postalcodeold
# 1          12345        1811BH
# 2          23456        1811LH
# 3          35678        1814XS
# 4          45698        1911HK
# 5          23651        1715PH
```